# Does Sch. 29 of the 2020 Coronavirus Act remain in effect or has it been repealed?

Tags: england-and-wales, covid-19

Corollary: if CA2020 no longer has effect either because it has been repealed, or because the prescribed period has simply expired, is there some reason why there has been no further updates to the prescribed AT forms like Form 3 which continues to make mention of the CA2020?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you browse to the ["latest available" version of Schedule 29](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2020/7/schedule/29/paragraph/1), it says:

> Sch. 29 expires (25.3.2022) by Coronavirus Act 2020 (c. 7), s. 89 (with s. 90)

[Section 89](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2020/7/section/89) provides that the Act expires "at the end of the period 2 years beginning with the day on which it is passed, subject to subsection (2) and section 90." Subsection 89(2) lists some parts of the Act that don't expire on that date, but Schedule 29 is not listed as one of those exceptions. And [s. 90](https://www.legislation.gov.uk/ukpga/2020/7/section/90) allowed the expiry date for a portion of the Act to be adjusted to be earlier in time, or later in time, but no later than six months after it would have otherwise expired.

Since the Act was passed on 25th March 2020, the latest that Schedule 29 could possibly have been in force is 25th September 2020. However, the annotation indicates no such extension was made, and it expired on 25th March 2022.

Answer (score 1):

Assured Tenancy Forms no longer reference the Coronavirus Act 2020.

The current ones may be found at the relevant [government web page](https://www.gov.uk/guidance/assured-tenancy-forms). (I've not checked them all, but Forms 1, 3 and 6A have been updated for sure.)